# How do you get the Route Params from a Lazy-Loaded child component (in Angular 7)?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

[image: Angularr route param issues]
How can you get the route params (e.g. companyId in the picture) from a child component?
So far, the following has not worked:

```
this.companyId = this.route.snapshot.params.companyId;
if (!this.companyId)
    this.companyId = this.route.parent.snapshot.params.companyId;
```

[StackBlitz](https://pegasi-crm-routing.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Can u share stackblitz `https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular`?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you add the option `{paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'}` in your `Router.forRoot` ?

Comment: @MartinPaucot thanks! that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option `{paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'}` to your `Router.forRoot()`.